# Using PHP variable in JavaScript for loop

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop

I'm trying to insert a php variable into a for loop in JS which creates a dropdown menu depending on the '$totalPages' varaible, here is my code:

```
<?php

$totalPages = 22;

?>

<script language="JavaScript">


    document.write("<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown' onchange='selectedItem(this.value)'>");
    for (var i=1; i <= <?php $totalPages ?>; i++)
    {


        document.write("<option>" + 'Page'+i + "</option>");

    }


    </script>
```

I'm receiving the error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;** on the first line of the for loop. I think it must be something to do with how i am referencing the variable in the for loop?

Comment: You need to `echo $totalPages`

Comment: language="Javascript" has been loooooong deprecated, and document.write is considered bad habit. But it should work as soon as you use echo

Comment: `<?echo $totalPages?>` or `<?= $totalPages?>`

Comment: Why are you using Javascript for that? Isn't this something you can easily render using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to echo the $totalPages variable. So the PHP part should read `<?php echo $totalPages; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot the generated JavaScript by using your Browsers "View Sourcecode" function.

In your case you are missing `echo`. Change your code to:

```
<?php

    $totalPages = 22;

?>

<script language="JavaScript">


document.write("<select name='dropdown' id='dropdown' onchange='selectedItem(this.value)'>");
for (var i=1; i <= <?php echo $totalPages ?>; i++)
{


    document.write("<option>" + 'Page'+i + "</option>");

}


</script>
```